# Sleep function not resolving promise passed into it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I came up with the following sleep function that I'm trying to perfect:

```
const sleep = (promise, milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(promise)
      }, milliseconds)
    }
    catch(err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

Here is an example using it:

```
let { error, stdout, stderr } = await sleep(exec(`aws s3api head-bucket --bucket pr-${bucketName}`), 2000)
```

the problem I have is I get the error sometimes(not always): `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Command failed: aws s3api head-bucket --bucket pr-11`

I'm not quite sure how to get my sleep function working.  I figured I'd just pass in the promise (in this case I'm passing in the promisified exec() call), do a timeout on it, and return it as a new promise after resolved in the timeout.

This actually works for me, it's just giving me that error but it is definitely working as far as my intention to resolve the passed promisified exec() and then returning its results wrapped in a promise again

```
const sleep = (promise, milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(promise)
      }, milliseconds)
  })
}
```

Basically I think what my function is doing is just taking in a promise, and then passing it back after x milliseconds..kinda like a handoff in sports :)...give and go

Comment: Uh, shouldn't that be just `await sleep(null, 2000); var result = await exec(…)`? If no, please tell us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Why is promise an argument? This function should *create* a promise.

And why is there a try-catch?  It can't fail.

All you need is this:

```
const sleep = milliseconds => 
   new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
```

**Edit:** remember that promises don't take call-backs and you don't have to manually wrap it in a try.  You use `.then()` and `.catch()` to compose promises.  The OP had a promisified exec and he wanted to combine it with sleep.  The possibilities are

```
const cmdPromise = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec)(cmd)
  .then(() => sleep(2000))
  .then(cmdPromise)
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error: " + e));
```

This waits 2 seconds, then runs the command, waits for it to complete, and prints "Done".

Or, you could

```
cmdPromise
  .then(() => sleep(2000))
  .then(() => console.log('Done'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error: " + e));
```

Which waits for the command to execute, then waits two more seconds, and prints "Done".

Or, and my guess is that this is what you want:

```
Promise.all([ cmdPromise,
              sleep(2000) ])
  .then(() => console.log('Done')
  .catch(e => console.log('Error: " + e));
```

This waits for *both* the command to finish and two seconds to elapse (in parallel) before printing "Done".

Comment: what if I send in a promise?  Then promise creates a promise around the promise sent in?

Comment: What would the sent-in promise be used for?  You gonna re-purpose it somehow?

Comment: it's the promisfied exec() call.  I'm using Node.js's new util.promisified wich wraps exec() in a promise.  I was using that before I tried to create this sleep function

Comment: also you need to fix  milliseconds)  just milliseconds or (milliseconds)

Comment: this should be able to take any kind of function, promise or not

Comment: What does the function or promise _do_?

Comment: it depends what I'm passing into this function.  I'm passing in a promisified exec().  exec() allows you to make cli calls, for example to aws..it's Node.js's exec() function

Comment: exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec),

Comment: so util.promisify(require('child_process').exec) is really what's being passed into the sleep

Comment: or put another way, it's new sleep(Promise(exec(`aws s3api head-bucket --bucket pr-${bucketName}`)), 2000) or something like that, you get the point.  But someone could just pass in a function that's not wrapped in a promise to, I'd like to get this working for the first scenario (passing in the promisified exec) but also want to make sure it works for anything passd in, even something that's not promisified or wrapped in a promise.  Maybe I should just require one thing and leave it as that?

Comment: can you show applying your function please.  You're not wrapping anything with it looks like, so are you just calling sleep(3000) and putting that before whatever call you're making?  Like I don't see how yours is receiving a function, it's just returning a promise that doesn't do anything looks like to me?

Comment: >And why is there a try-catch? It can't fail.  - Yes it can...If I passed in the promisified exec, yes the exec() call could fail

Comment: the reason I had resolve(promise) was I was resolving the exec() call that's wrapped in a promise.  Then wrapping that yielded exec call again in a promise so I can await again after the sleep...hence yield the yielded exec() promise

Comment: crap yea, I can't wrap the promise in a try, duh..you're right.  I've been doing so much async/await that I completely goofed on that one

Comment: interesting, how are you able to chain by adding .sleep(2000) after (cmd)...how do you make that chainable here in JS?

Comment: fyi es7's promise.all() only takes one param, an iterable

Comment: Promises are inherently chainable, that's what promisify does.

Comment: I don't know man your stuff isn't working for me..tried your Promise.all.  I tried putting in the exe() as the first item in the array and sleep in the second, but it's not liking the syntax.

Comment: this bombs out let { error, stdout, stderr } = await Promise.all([exec(`aws s3api head-bucket --bucket ${bucketName}`), sleep(2000)]). Maybe you were thinking something else, please show an example with my code...and besides how would I even get sdtout, error, etc. from my resolved exec() call

Comment: Perhaps you should make another question about this, but `await Promise.all([])` cannot be good code.  Try `await(Promise.all([]))`.  The question about stdout and exec() is a third question.